# PhantomJS: Wait for page execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs

I need phantomJS to wait for sometime after clicking the button inorder to get result. This result is stored in a div tag. I want to do something with this result.

I understood that javascript does not have sleep() like other languages

I tried using,

```
setTimeout(function () {
           var b = $("#idresult").text();
                        console.log("In windows timeout"+b);

        }, 10000);
```

And

```
function sleep(delay) {
                var start = new Date().getTime();
                while (new Date().getTime() < start + delay);
            }
```

Calling of sleep

```
$("#idrun").click();
 sleep(100000);
```

But neither of them worked. These two functions are placed in page.evaluate().
Any other ways to do this.

I really appreciate your help!

Comment: setTimeout() should do the trick, what was the problem with that solution?

Comment: @ppajer I understood that it is not executing setTimeout func. It is not being logged in console.

Answer (score 0):

Just wait inside of PhantomJS script, then evaluate:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    page.evaluate(function(){
        var b = $("#idresult").text();
        console.log("In windows timeout"+b);
    });
}, 10000);
```